# How to access the instance opening a class?

Tags: ruby

Given the following situation:

```
class Foo
  def my_method
    # Do something
  end

  def another_method
    bar = Bar.new
  end
end
```

I basically want to copy Foo's method onto bar.

I tried:

```
def bar.my_method
  my_method
end
```

And:

```
Class << bar
  def my_method
    my_method
  end
end
```

But both end up with a stack-level to deep error.

How can I access Foo's method while declaring a method onto the instance bar?

Comment: Well, there's no instance of `Foo` at that point. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I edited my answer, bar is supposed to be called from another instance_method on Foo. This should clear things up.

Comment: The problem I think you'll run into is that you can't bind a Class's methods to another instance of a Class: `TypeError: bind argument must be an instance of Foo`. Note that this restriction is not true for Modules (so if you refactor Foo's method into a Module then you'll be able to do this)

Comment: Nope, still not clear. Why the "copying"? Just pass a `Foo` to the `bar` and call method on it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify my comment, you can't transplant methods between classes of different ancestry:

```
class Bar; end

class Foo
  def my_method
    puts self.class.name
  end
end

bar = Bar.new

bar.define_singleton_method(:my_method, Foo.instance_method(:my_method))
#=> TypeError: bind argument must be a subclass of Foo
```

The problem here is that `Foo.instance_method(:my_method)` is not yet bound to an evaluation context. In addition, Ruby has the restriction that an instance method can only be bound to a context if the context inherits from the method's owner (in this case, `bar` doesn't inherit from `Foo` so we get an error)

But you can refactor this to use a module instead which has looser restrictions:

```
module MyMethodProvider
  def my_method
    puts self.class.name
  end
end

class Foo
  include MyMethodProvider
end

class Bar; end

bar = Bar.new

bar.singleton_class.include(MyMethodProvider)

bar.my_method
#=> Bar
```

Comment: or just `bar.extend MyMethodProvider`